# VEGA pie chart with labels - wrong position of labels

Tags: vega, mindsphere

i tried to make piechart for Downtimes by machine. My input is:

"values": [{"Prostoj": "1-5min", "value": 10467, "textik":"02:54:27"},

```
       {"Prostoj": "5-12min", "value": 1470, "textik":"00:24:30"},

       {"Prostoj": "12-35min", "value": 5100, "textik":"01:25:00"},

       {"Prostoj": ">35min", "value": 1000, "textik":"00:00:00"}]
```

who "Prostoj" is Downtime-class, "value" is downtime in seconds and "textik" is label for piechart. My code in Vega-lite is this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with labels.",
  "height":"container",
  "width":"container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Prostoj": "1-5min", "value": 10467, "textik":"02:54:27"},
      {"Prostoj": "5-12min", "value": 1470, "textik":"00:24:30"},
      {"Prostoj": "12-35min", "value": 5100, "textik":"01:25:00"},
      {"Prostoj": ">35min", "value": 1000, "textik":"00:00:00"}
     
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true}
    
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {
      "type": "arc", 
      "outerRadius": 150, 
      "padAngle":0.1, 
      "cornerRadius":10
      },
    "encoding": {
      "color":{
        "field":"Prostoj",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale":{
          "domain":["1-5min", "5-12min", "12-35min", ">35min"],
          "range":["#00FFB9", "yellow", "orange", "red"]
        },
        "legend":null
      }
    }
    
  }, {
    "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 100, "fontSize":12, "fontWeight":"bold"},
    "encoding": {
      "angle":{"value":0},
      "theta":{"field":"value", "type": "quantitative", "stack":true},
      "text": {"field": "Prostoj", "type": "nominal"}
    }
  }]
}
```

but I have Probem with labels if i choose "Prostoj" as label are the labels on the right position, but if I choose for label variable "textik" then is the labelposition in graph wrong. Can somebody help me?
[right position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX9Mh.jpg)
[wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9381.jpg)
Tahnk you very much in advance. Miroslav

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by *right* and *wrong* positions?

Comment: Yes of course - as you see my input - the highest record is 
{"Prostoj": "1-5min", "value": 10467, "textik":"02:54:27"} 
value=10467, 
in piechart also is the bigest green piece with label "1-5min". 
If I choose as label variable "Prostoj" is label to green piece of chart "1-5min". Label is on right position on green color. 
But if I choose as label variable "textik" label "02:54:27" is not on green color. Is by orange color... I hope now it is clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have scales contradicting one another which is confusing. This should work for you.

[Editor.](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHBSJnEERKijHA0ZFhoIFBymEg0snDq-i7K9KHhspHRsf7KSJFooMRIggxqaADaoAAK6mwQmGySoQCM-GII0f75hXBoDQAMACwAbADsSphwAB46ANahPQBMqGJ9qHNDIAC+ChVVNXWhYvwNc63ySh1F3X1DPaMT07M9K8sAzD0bWyCV1bX16Ef8zxabTOBQui16NxAY0mNBm6B6DRWYlQPTem223z26AAfICTu1QV1UBDIdD7vDHqiUWiALqbEBwWThZTRMi5KHwHKoUAAMxsgmUoXOXVGAE8cESQABHBhIVJ0bI0Uj+GpIKBwzDqIr08KCNhxbkgPneQXoL67epiiWhWRsE4FfwWMiM02yBiCQRKaAFImgZR2qJ6EogJpA04gA5HfFKf544EgXFhkA0pTqOXO0ogADEqIAYrmAEIATn8ou8eqc-n16ZFIHUcEFdPW9I8ZYNZRAyHUcNAmHFkvsUCrDDG6gASkgWQwIN0xJCcJP9LIyBY0D1KA0lOF1DFx5OaNPuj1mx8uz2of3QmT-GmpzPiailDyIgBlGgALyJRyfEQA6oFgkwUImDYAV-D5D1gI8dV3gZJk2BZZd2WvQ1jTA9AyVhfw+2tdBbXtQQNmbOkgA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with labels.",
  "height":"container",
  "width":"container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Prostoj": "1-5min", "value": 10467, "textik":"02:54:27"},
      {"Prostoj": "5-12min", "value": 1470, "textik":"00:24:30"},
      {"Prostoj": "12-35min", "value": 5100, "textik":"01:25:00"},
      {"Prostoj": ">35min", "value": 1000, "textik":"00:00:00"}
     
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true}
    
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {
      "type": "arc", 
      "outerRadius": 150, 
      "padAngle":0.1, 
      "cornerRadius":10
      },
    "encoding": {
      "color":{
        "field":"Prostoj",
        "type": "nominal",
        "scale":{
          "domain":["1-5min", "5-12min", "12-35min", ">35min"],
          "range":["#00FFB9", "yellow", "orange", "red"]
        },
        "legend":null
      }
    }
    
  }, {
    "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 100, "fontSize":12, "fontWeight":"bold"},
    "encoding": {
      "angle":{"value":0},
      "theta":{"field":"value", "type": "quantitative", "stack":true},
      "text": {"field": "Prostoj", "type": "nominal"}
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much David, now its work fine, thank you. I still have to learn.